# JPA/Hibernate: What use is an ORM (Hibernate) when it doesn't get all JPA mappings right?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, mapping

I've played a lot with Hibernate and JPA mapping in the last couple of months/weeks. My DB uses composite primary keys and I've reported approximately 10 to 15 Hibernate and 5-10 EclipseLink bugs. Hibernate is especially ridiculous in certain constellations that ought to be working. (I had the code checked by experts and JPA book authors)

The big question is:

What use is an ORM when it doesn't get **all** JPA mappings right?

Hibernate has soo much to offer, caching etcetc. I wonder who cares when developers can't even get past creating a working meta data model... It's all pointless. So again, what use is an ORM when it doesn't get **all** JPA mappings right?

Comment: I've used hibernate for 4 years in multiple projects and haven't had any significant issue with it. So the problem should be you ;)

Comment: As I've done extensive testing with the 4 possible composite primary key variants JPA 1.0 @IdClass, JPA 1.0 @EmbeddedId, JPA 2.0 @IdClass, and JPA 2.0 @EmbeddedId with Hibernate and EclipseLink, the problem definfitely is Hibernate handling composite keys badly. You either don't use composite primary keys or you're using JPA 1.0 @IdClass implementations. These are the only ones that are stable in Hibernate (3.6).

Comment: This is flamebait.  It doesn't seem to me like you were open for any other answer than "Yes, you are right!  Any ORM that doesn't implement the full JPA 2 spec is useless."  It seems to me that you just want to let out your frustration about Hibernate and want to get reassured by others.  SO is not the right place for this kind of communication.

Comment: Yes, I want to be reassured by others. Other ORMs like EclipseLink have errors that still make me scratch my head, too. It's not only about Hibernate but all JPA ORMs. Hibernate is just by far the most buggy one when it comes to mappings. The rest of the software becomes useless when JPA providers don't understand that without all JPA mappings working newcomers will always end up thinking JPA and ORM are useless technologies. My mission is to improve JPA implementations.

Comment: I had a hard time finding out what the problem was with Hibernate and EclipseLink. I realized they're all buggy/incomplete to some degree and I started to wonder what use such a software has. It's not satisfactory to have 1 of 4 composite primary key variants work, they *all* have to work.

Comment: I'm with you Kawu, Just yesterday I noticed Hibernate JPA generated a silly sql query for an entity that has an ElementCollection<Enum> and an @OneToMany fields along with other properties.. you know what the left join query has populated duplicated items in my OneToMany as many as my ElementCollection field. very silly & basic bug.

Answer (score 5):

ORM is a tool. Ponder that sentence deeply.

It is usually believed that if a piece technology, Hibernate in this case, becomes popular enough in a specific domain, it is the silver bullet and that you have to use it, otherwise you're a loser.

This is plainly and utterly wrong. Hibernate is a tool that should be used appropriately.

Hibernate's authors say that Hibernate is best suited for new projects, where mappings are defined in xml or using annotations, and then Hibernate generates the DLL for your database and creates all tables and relationships.

The reverse can be very tricky, especially when you've got non normalized tables and composite primary keys.

That's why Hibernate strongly encourages use of primary surrogate keys that are autoincrementing.

Doing proper JPA reverse mapping is a challenge with many corner cases awaiting you in the wild, so you're doing the right thing by report all these bugs so they can be fixed. With some more persistence, I'm sure you'll be able to do your mappings perfectly and then everything after that should be much easier, since that first part is always the hardest.

Comment: I think the recommendation to use surrogate keys just hints they have problems getting composite key mappings right. I did extensive testing over the last couple of weeks using JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0 plus @IdClass and @EmbeddedId composite key class mappings. Result: Hibernate manages only 1 of 4 (JPA 1.0 @IdClass), whereas EclipseLink manages 3 of 4 (JPA 1.0 @IdClass, JPA 1.0 @EmbeddedId, and JPA 2.0 @IdClass), which makes Hibernate nearly useless and extremely developer unfriendly (hard to debug the real cause), ultimately making Hibernate only a second choice on the market.

Comment: I'm not going to change my DB because of an inferior ORM tool, but I'd rather switch to another that works better or at least gets any bugs fixed at all. You sometimes encounter EclipseLink developers on their forums which urged me to create bug reports. The same never happened with Hibernate, so you get the feeling the Hibernate developers work on other stuff. I think it's pretty stupid to enhance back side parts of the software when the front side (mappings!) aren't working satisfyingly...

Comment: @Kawu: maybe Hibernate developers were busy improving and fixing Hibernate, instead of urging you to create bug reports.

Comment: None of my 10-15 bug reports I've entered in the last months has ever received a status update or even a comment. When you walk around on the JBoss site and watch the activity that is tracked there it is mostly about pieces of the software that deal with caching algorithms and other advanced stuff. I wouldn't just blame them without knowing...

Comment: I would have created the bug reports nontheless, even without being asked to do so. The difference is, this gives you the feeling someone is really interested in your problems. The Hibernate bug tracker is currently just a black hole that you throw stuff into...

Comment: @Kawu: I see you have many negative feelings about Hibernate. If it doesn't work for you, you don't have to use it.

Comment: @darioo: I see you have many positive feelings about Hibernate. If it works out for you, don't assume it works out for others. But then, no one will stop me from expressing my discoveries and opinions. Hibernate is clearly overrated as a JPA mapper and I won't recommend it anymore, especially when composite primary keys are involved. Hibernate there fails more than it works and I can prove that...

Comment: -1 Because of the first 2 sentences, I read the rest you are technically right, especially the conclusion. But the beginning make readers thinks this is an opinion based answer.

Answer (score 3):

With whatever problem I have with JPA, I create a testcase for all implementations and compare the behavior of the ORMs and the reactions of their communities. Hibernate is by far the worst - their JPA bugs are not even looked at. OpenJPA is somewhat behind EclipseLink feature wise but it looks stable. EclipseLink has bugs which still take some time, but there is activity and frequent upgrades. My questions in the mailing list were all answered in a professional way by Oracle people. It appears that currently EclipseLink is the winner. I am using composite primary keys without problems - without them I still would need secondary unique indexes. It is really useful being able to look up entities by a composite key so the surrogate key workaround seems to be an excuse to me. In EclipseLink one can even use an enum as primary key which is really useful for those numerous little lookup tables that control system behavor. See http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/JPA-7

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. I'm really glad you mentioned the ENUM PK issue on Hibernate, which I would have created for one of the tables in one of my next DB extensions.

Comment: Update: the "no ENUM as PK issue" in Hibernate appears to be solved. I've just tried it with Hibernate 3.6.0. There's no problem using em.find(...) to find an entity that has an ENUM in its composite PK.